# Terminating multiple background processes in bash?

Tags: bash, process, terminate

I'm trying to dump trade-data off binance for multiple symbol-pairs, e.g. doge/btc, ada/btc, etc.

I can background, thus:

```
wscat -c wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/dogebtc@trade > doge.txt &
wscat -c wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/adabtc@trade > ada.txt &
```

But how to terminate them all?

Is there some smart way, like terminating the parent process?

Comment: `pkill wcat`, if your system has it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the right answer depends a lot on the way your current system is implemented / used.

At the most basic scripting level, you could simply run `kill` against all `wscat` processes; but that may be too generic depending on the details.

Slightly better, in a BASH script, directly after creating these processes you'd have access to their PID as `$!`. You could stash those PIDs in a variable or file and later use them to `kill` each individual process.

If you're aiming for something slicker than that, you'd likely want to look into things like:
the `SIGCHLD` signal, becoming a `subreaper` (`prctl` `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER`), running as PID 1 in a PID-namespace (`unshare --pid ...`), things like that.